# Retrofit call in non-activity class

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am beginner to android, am using Retrofit 2.0 for http calls. Since, I use same call in different activities, I created the function in non-activity class.

Here my retrofit calls in non-activity class code,

```
public class ServerRequests {


private static ServerRequests serverRequests = new ServerRequests();

public static ServerRequests getInstance(){

    return serverRequests;
    }

public LoginResponse ClientLogin(final LoginRequest request, Context context){

    final ProgressDialog dialog = DialogueUtils.getInstance().showProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    dialog.show();

    RestApi mApi = RetrofitProvider.getInstance().getRestApi();

    Call<UserToken> call = mApi.clientLogin(request);

    // Stores Login response
    final LoginResponse loginResponse = new LoginResponse();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<UserToken>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserToken> call, Response<UserToken> response) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                loginResponse.setMloginstatus(true);
                loginResponse.setStatusCode(response.code());
                loginResponse.setUserToken(response.body());

                return;
            }

            // response isn't successful
            loginResponse.setMloginstatus(false);
            loginResponse.setStatusCode(response.code());
            loginResponse.setMessage(response.message());
            loginResponse.setUserToken(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UserToken> call, Throwable t) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            loginResponse.setMloginstatus(false);
            loginResponse.setUserToken(null);
            loginResponse.setMessage(t.getMessage());
            loginResponse.setStatusCode(FAILURE_ERROR);
        }
    });

    return loginResponse;
}
}
```

I will make call to above function in Activity class,
Here is the code,

```
LoginRequest request = new LoginRequest();
request.setPassword(PASSWORD);
request.setEmail(USER_NAME); 

// Calling Login function

LoginResponse response = ServerRequests.getInstance().ClientLogin(request, this);
```

Here, before receiving response in activity class, next set of code lines are executing. So, Activity class doesn't waiting till function to return back to the calling sequence.

Can anyone please suggest me what's the better approach to do this.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use a interface to handle callback.

Step1: Define an interface

```
public interface LoginListener{
 public void success(Response<UserToken> response);
 public void failed(String message);
}
```

Step2: Use this interface on the method that you use retrofit.

```
public LoginResponse ClientLogin(final LoginRequest request, Context context, LoginListener listener){

    final ProgressDialog dialog = DialogueUtils.getInstance().showProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    dialog.show();

    RestApi mApi = RetrofitProvider.getInstance().getRestApi();

    Call<UserToken> call = mApi.clientLogin(request);

    // Stores Login response
    final LoginResponse loginResponse = new LoginResponse();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<UserToken>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserToken> call, Response<UserToken> response) {
            dialog.dismiss();

            listener.success(response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UserToken> call, Throwable t) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            listener.failed("message error");
        }
    });

    return loginResponse;
}
```

I hope, This way can help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can't return the result from your method, because you're making the Retrofit call asynchronously.  Use a callback instead.

```
public interface GenericCallback<T> {

void success(T result);
void failure(... whatever you need);
}

public void ClientLogin(final LoginRequest request, Context context, final GenericCallback<LoginResponse> callback){

    final ProgressDialog dialog = DialogueUtils.getInstance().showProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    dialog.show();

    RestApi mApi = RetrofitProvider.getInstance().getRestApi();

    Call<UserToken> call = mApi.clientLogin(request);

    // Stores Login response
    final LoginResponse loginResponse = new LoginResponse();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<UserToken>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserToken> call, Response<UserToken> response) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                loginResponse.setMloginstatus(true);
                loginResponse.setStatusCode(response.code());
                loginResponse.setUserToken(response.body());

                callback.success(loginResponse);
                return;
            }

            // response isn't successful
            loginResponse.setMloginstatus(false);
            loginResponse.setStatusCode(response.code());
            loginResponse.setMessage(response.message());
            loginResponse.setUserToken(null);

            callback.failure(...);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UserToken> call, Throwable t) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            loginResponse.setMloginstatus(false);
            loginResponse.setUserToken(null);
            loginResponse.setMessage(t.getMessage());
            loginResponse.setStatusCode(FAILURE_ERROR);
            callback.failure(...);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`call.enqueue()` is asynchronous.. the call is done in the background, and then, as soon as the call finishes, one of the two callbacks is called, either `onResponse` or `onFailure`.

`call.execute()` is synchronous, it will block the execution until the call finishes, but in that case you need to handle threading manually (remember that in android you cannot block the UI thread).

I recommend `enqueue`.